# Sri Keyuravati of krama tradition

Tags: guru, life, kashmiri-shaivism

I would like to know information on Sri keyuravati of Kashmir shaivism who was a central figure in krama lineage.

Would like to know about life. Important events and books written if any.

Also about guru and sishyas

Comment: Was she direct disciple of Acharya VasuGupta ?

Comment: see the chart in the pdf posted below

Answer (score 5):

We find a reference of her as the Guru of Govindaraja and as the disciple of a Sri Vidya Parampara Guru called Shiva Ananda Natha.

One special type of Shakta Yoga, which is related to the Shambhopaya technique of the Trika system, is called "Kalinaya".

Keyuravati was adept in this form and was an important female Guru in this lineage too.

> There is a special type of shAkta yoga known as kAlInaya. It was
>   originated by one shivAnandanAtha about whom we know very little. He
>   imparted it to **three female disciples named keyUravatI, kalyANikA and
>   madanikA. We know that govindarAja learnt it from keyUravatI and then
>   imparted it to the great philosopher somAnanda.** kAlInaya reached
>   abhinavagupta through the line of ujjaTa, udbhaTa etc. erakanAtha, the
>   disciple of kalyANikA, engaged himself in attaining supernatural
>   powers and did not initiate any disciple in the path. This information
>   about the origin and spread of kAlInaya has been provided by jayaratha
>   in his commentary on tantrAloka. He bases the information on the
>   kramakeli of abhinavagupta and quotes a long passage from it. Passages
>   in kAshmIra-apabhramsha, quoted by abhinavagupta in his tantrasAra and
>   parAtrimshikAvivaraNa, may have been drawn from the sayings of works
>   of the above mentioned three female preceptors. These three highly
>   respected yoginis may have preferred to teach in the language of the
>   common people, as did lalleshvarI in the fourteenth century A.D.
>   shivAnanda, being the great-grand teacher of somAnanda, may have
>   flourished sometime in the eighth century A.D.

Source - [Shakta Yoga and the Twelve Kalis](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=859&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1)

Comment: You mean Kali Mata? I m talking abt Shivanandanatha @RakeshJoshi

Comment: Btw Kali Mata is also allied to Sri Vidya as noted in Nityotsava and Vidyarnava tantram both ... Ananda Natha is the suffix added to Sri Vidya initiates only @RakeshJoshi Also, as u can see, the article is also tagged with Sri Vidya

Comment: No, they are 12 forms of Goddess Kali only .. Read the 8th and 9th paras of the linked article starting with this line " The term kAlInaya can be understood as follows. " @Partha

Comment: http://shaivayoga.com/kashmir-manuscripts_files/Intro_Krama.pdf   in this pdf see the lineage jnana netra and mangalaa ...

Comment: I assumed the Guru to be from Sri Vidya because of the suffix name Ananda Natha and also because the article itself is tagged with Sri Vidya .. So, with that PDF u can write ur own answer @RakeshJoshi

Comment: ananda natha is for most of shaktas... not only ssri vidya,,, even natha is common